# Pages: frontpage.php, home.php, posts page etc

Tags: theme-development, pages

When do I use the following:

- home.php
- frontpage.php
- Under Settings > Reading Settings

  - Front Page
  - Posts Page

I wish to clarify this as I find myself using "Placeholder Pages", empty pages just for the sake of a menu item and to display blog listings.

If I use a Static Front Page (Set under Settings > Reading Settings > Front Page) how do I access my posts page? Do I need to have a "Placeholder Page" titled blog and use `page-blog.php`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't ever directly *use* (as in, select as a Page template) either `front-page.php` or `home.php`. WordPress uses these template files automatically, according to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) rules.

- The `front-page.php` template file is used to display **Site Front Page**, whether you have set the site front page to display a *static Page* or the *Blog Posts Index*.
- The `home.php` template file is used to display the **Blog Posts Index**, whether the blog posts index is set to display on the *Site Front Page* or an a *separate static Page*.
- The `front-page.php` template file will override `home.php` on the **Site Front Page**.
- The `home.php` template file will override `page.php` (or any `page-{custom-template}.php` selections) on *non-front page static Pages`.

> If I use a Static Front Page (Set under Settings > Reading Settings > Front Page) how do I access my posts page? Do I need to have a "Placeholder Page" titled blog and use page-blog.php?

To display the **Blog Posts Index** on a non-front page static Page:

- Create a new static Page, with any arbitrary title ("Blog", "News", or anything else you want), and leave the Page Content blank/empty
- Under `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`, set "Posts Page" to the static Page you just created.

Really; that's it. If you want to customize the display of your static-page-as-blog-posts-index, simply modify the `home.php` template file. Creating a `page-blog.php` template file will have no effect.

Comment: You said "You don't ever directly use (as in, select as a Page template)", do you mean if I want a static front page, I should create a page like "Home" with no content, create a custom template for it `page-home.php` then select that to be the home page?

Comment: @jiewmeng see the *[Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)* Codex entry. The only time that creating your own custom page template for a static front page will work is if your Theme does *not* include a `front-page.php` template file. See also: *[Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)*.

Comment: In other words, I should create a `page-home.php` and an empty page "Home" if I want to have my front page display my latest 3 posts & latest 3 portfolio (custom post type)? Just to confirm my understanding

Comment: "*I should create a page-home.php and an empty page "Home" if I want to have my front page display my latest 3 posts & latest 3 portfolio (custom post type)?*" - actually, I would use **`front-page.php`** for that purpose. That way, you don't have to worry about selecting the custom page template; instead, you simply select the appropriate static Page via `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`, and you're done.